# TextInput's autoCorrect's behaviour is different in iPhone SE compared to other iPhone modals

Tags: iphone, react-native, ios12, ios15

I have `TextInput` with `autoCorrect` prop

```
<TextInput
     placeholder={placeholderText}
     value={this.props.value}
     onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
     autoCorrect={false}
/>
```

If the `autoCorrect` is set to `false`, Then there are no predictions in `iPhone 6(iOS 12`) and `iPhone 11(iOS 15)`, Which means working as expected. But surprisingly in `iPhone SE(iOS 15)` still predictions are appearing though `autoCorrect` is set to `false`. Which means predictions are appearing irrespective of `autoCorrect` value in `iPhone SE`.

Can some one explain the reason behind this phenomenon please?
Thank You.

Comment: I do not have this on my iPhone SE (1st Gen.) with iOS 15. But when I turn Autocorrection on in the system settings, I get an empty bar above the keyboard.

Comment: @Christian in my case, it's happening in both 1'st gen and 2'nd gen. BTW, Did you try with `React-Native` app?

Comment: yes, I did it with my own react native app with different fields.